# How robust is the asp.net profile system? Is it ready for prime time?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I've used asp.net profiles (using the AspNetSqlProfileProvider) for holding small bits of information about my users. I started to wonder how it would handle a robust profile for a large number of users. Does anyone have experience using this on a large website with large numbers of simultaneous users? What are the performance implications? How about maintenance?

Answer (score 1):

Running against this via SQL I have found is a bit tricky, but i have worked with clients that have scaled it up to a few hundred properties, and 10K+ users without difficulty.  Granted not a lot of users but it is working thus far.

I think it really depends on the specific project, and your exact needs when it comes to working with the profile information.  Do you need to query on it regularly via SQL?  Do you just need to for user display only, these types of things might help provide a more solid answer for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL provider performance is more closely correlated to big iron throughput.  Performance is more or less directly proportional to a single SQL Server's ability to handle the number of queries.  Scale-up is the only option, so as such its not really five-nines robust out the box.

You'll have to figure out if you need scale-out performance and availability e.g. through partitioning, replication, redundancy etc. and at what cost to performance.  Some of the capabilities are are possible as is - the current implementation is more aimed at the middle-market and enterprise.

Good thing is you can put your own implementation of the profile provider - then attach it to services and systems with capabilities outlined above.

We wrote a custom authn,authz and profile provider and strapped it to large AD/LDS LDAP cluster across 3 datacenters.  We're in the Comscore Top 10 - so you could say that we deal with a good slice of internet every day.  1000's of profile queries per second and 100'millions of profiles - it can scale with good planning, engineering and operations.